# Inserting multiple objects into array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to insert 3 objects of different classes into an array, such that, the array looks like this `[objA,.., objA, objB,.., objB, objC,..., objC]`. 
The way I have my function set up is to get a rand for number of times each of objA, objB and objC will be inserted into the array, then have 3 for loops to insert each of the objects.

```
    $no_of_objA = rand(5, 10);
    $no_of_objB = rand(1, 5);
    $no_of_objC = rand(3, 8);

    for($i = 0; $i < $no_of_objA; $i++)
        $this->users[$i] = new A();

    for($i = $no_of_objA; $i < ($no_of_objA + $no_of_objB); $i++)
        $this->users[$i] = new B();

    for($i = ($no_of_objA + $no_of_objB); $i < ($no_of_objA + $no_of_objB + $no_of_objC); $i++)
        $this->users[$i] = new C();
```

The worst case for this obviously will be Big-O of largest number generated form the rand function.
This works fine, but, I'm kind of thinking there may be a more elegant and optimized solution to achieving this.

I'm not really concerned by the order the objects are inserted...

Comment: free cookie if any one knows what the OP is doing

Comment: I won't get a free cookie....

Comment: @Rasclatt can i sell ya one? :)

Comment: @Dagon As long as I don't have to try and wrap my head around a similar algorithm scheme, then maybe...I'm a cheap-skate though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about tracking with IDs

```
$a_count = mt_rand(5, 10); //Faster than rand
$b_count = mt_rand(1, 5);
$c_count = mt_rand(3, 8);

for($i = 0;$i < $a_count; $i++){
    $this->users[] = new A();
}
for($i = 0;$i < $b_count; $i++){
    $this->users[] = new B();
}
for($i = 0;$i < $c_count; $i++){
    $this->users[] = new C();
}
```

Comment: This actually produces exactly the same result as the code in the question, since PHP will automatically index the array starting at 0. It is more elegant in that the loops are simpler but it produces the same result. It is not any faster, and I don't think a faster solution exists. Creating and inserting `n` objects is obviously `O(n)`.